# How to keep selection but also press button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this text. On select, a div will appear that has multiple colors. On click of the blue div or the first color div, the text should highlight the text that is currently highlighted. This only works if I remove the conditional if statement for the `#blue_box`. I think the click element is removing the selection of the text before the program can retrieve the text. How can I keep the click element, but also track the selection?

```js
$("#actual_verse").mouseup(function() {
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }

  if (/\S/.test(text)) {
    $("#blue_box").click(function() {
      var range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      var contents = range.extractContents();
      var node = document.createElement('span');
      node.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      node.appendChild(contents);
      range.insertNode(node);
    });

    // Tool Tip

    var ele = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var rel1 = document.createRange();
    rel1.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal1'));
    var rel2 = document.createRange();
    rel2.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal2'));
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
      if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
        var r = sel.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
        var rb1 = rel1.getBoundingClientRect();
        var rb2 = rel2.getBoundingClientRect();
        //this will place ele below the selection
        ele.style.top = (r.bottom - rb2.top) * 100 / (rb1.top - rb2.top) + 'px';
        //this will align the right edges together
        ele.style.left = (r.left - rb2.left) * 100 / (rb1.left - rb2.left) + 'px';

        //code to set content

        ele.style.display = 'block';
      }
    });

    // End of Tool Tip
  }

});
```

```css
/* Tool Kit */

#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border: grey solid 1px;
  background: #373737;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#cal1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  overflow: none;
  z-index: -100;
}
#cal2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: none;
  z-index: -100;
}
.boxes {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}
#blue_box {
  background: #AAF6FF;
}
#green_box {
  background: #D6FFAA;
}
#orange_box {
  background: #FFBF98;
}
#purple_box {
  background: #D7D5FC;
}
#red_box {
  background: #FF9B9F;
}
#yellow_box {
  background: #FFF8AA;
}
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='actual_verse' class='context'> Hello There! </span>
<div id='cal1'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='cal2'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='tooltip'>
  <div id='blue_box' class='boxes' title='Blue'></div>
  <div id='green_box' class='boxes' title='Green'></div>
  <div id='orange_box' class='boxes' title='Orange'></div>
  <div id='purple_box' class='boxes' title='Purple'></div>
  <div id='red_box' class='boxes' title='Red'></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Hello, after searching around, I found out this example that may help you: http://jsfiddle.net/jrdGW/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the following changes accomplish what you desire.

**Changes:**

1. Moved `$("#blue_box").click(function(){}` out of your `#actual_verse` `mouseup` event handler.  You were adding yet another click handler for the blue box every time there was a `mouseup` event on `#actual_verse`. It should only be added once. Alternately, you can define the function in the global scope and name it.  Then you can add it and remove it multiple times.
2. Add a `mousedown` handler on the `#tooltip` which just calls [`event.preventDefalut()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). The `mousedown` event is the one that clears the selection. This happens before the click event, so by the time you were getting to your click handler there was no selection.
3. Add [`selection.removeAllRanges();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/removeAllRanges) to the end of the `blue_box` `click` handler to clear the selection to show the highlight. I'm assuming this is desirable. For me as a user, this is what I expect to happen.
4. Create `hideTooltip()` and add it to the end of the `blue_box` event handler. As a user, I expect the tooltip to disappear once I have made that click.
5. Remove the `window.addEventListener('mouseup',` but leave the code which it was executing. I'm not sure why that code was a `window` `mouseup` handler. Where it was being added as an event listener resulted in yet another copy of the handler added every time the `#actual_verse` `mouseup` event handler executed, just like was happening with the `blue_box` `click` handler.

```js
$("#tooltip").mousedown(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

//Only add the listener once, not another listener each mouseup
$("#blue_box").click(function() {
  var selection = document.getSelection();
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  var contents = range.extractContents();
  var node = document.createElement('span');
  node.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  node.appendChild(contents);
  range.insertNode(node);
  selection.removeAllRanges(); //Clear the selection, showing highlight
  hideTooltip();
});

function hideTooltip() {
  document.getElementById('tooltip').style.display = ''; //hide the tooltip
}

$("#actual_verse").mouseup(function() {
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }

  if (/\S/.test(text)) {
    // Tool Tip
    var ele = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var rel1 = document.createRange();
    rel1.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal1'));
    var rel2 = document.createRange();
    rel2.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal2'));

    if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
      var r = sel.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
      var rb1 = rel1.getBoundingClientRect();
      var rb2 = rel2.getBoundingClientRect();
      //this will place ele below the selection
      ele.style.top = (r.bottom - rb2.top) * 100 / (rb1.top - rb2.top) + 'px';
      //this will align the right edges together
      ele.style.left = (r.left - rb2.left) * 100 / (rb1.left - rb2.left) + 'px';
      //code to set content
      ele.style.display = 'block';
    }
    // End of Tool Tip
  }
});
```

```css
/* Tool Kit */

#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border: grey solid 1px;
  background: #373737;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#cal1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  overflow: none;
  z-index: -100;
}
#cal2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: none;
  z-index: -100;
}
.boxes {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}
#blue_box {
  background: #AAF6FF;
}
#green_box {
  background: #D6FFAA;
}
#orange_box {
  background: #FFBF98;
}
#purple_box {
  background: #D7D5FC;
}
#red_box {
  background: #FF9B9F;
}
#yellow_box {
  background: #FFF8AA;
}
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='actual_verse' class='context'> Hello There! </span>
<div id='cal1'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='cal2'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='tooltip'>
  <div id='blue_box' class='boxes' title='Blue'></div>
  <div id='green_box' class='boxes' title='Green'></div>
  <div id='orange_box' class='boxes' title='Orange'></div>
  <div id='purple_box' class='boxes' title='Purple'></div>
  <div id='red_box' class='boxes' title='Red'></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```